# How to count number of groups?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, distinct

I have a table as follow:

```
id    g_n   val_name  
---------------------
1      a      "a"
2      a      "aa"
3      b      "123"
4      b      "asad"
5      c      "aas1"
```

I want to count the number of distinct `g_n`. (Here it's `3`.)

I have tried with:

```
select count(*)
from table_t
group by g_n
```

But it gives me the number of items per group.

How can I count the number of *distinct* `g_n`?

Comment: It is crucial to know whether NULL values can be involved and should be counted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `count(distinct)`:

```
select count(distinct g_n)
from table_t;
```

There is no need to aggregate using `group by` for this result.

Note:  This ignores `NULL` values.  If you want to count them as well, then:

```
select count(distinct g_n) + max( (g_n is null)::int )
```

Comment: Indeed, if you group by, you'll get 3 rows of 1,1,1.. Might be worth a note though that that counts all nulls as 1, whereas it could be interpreted that each null is different from other nulls

Answer (score 2):

This also counts NULL values in `g_n` (adds 1 if any):

```
SELECT count(*)             -- count(*) counts *all* rows
FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT ON (g_n) FROM tbl) sub;
```

The `SELECT` list in the subquery can stay empty because `count(*)` in the outer `SELECT` does not consider row values anyway, only counts rows (which ist the reason why it is faster than `count(expression)`).

It is also typically faster than the `DISTINCT` clause in the aggregate expression:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT g_n)  -- count(expression) ignores NULL values
FROM   tbl;
```

But to get a **truly fast count of *few* distinct `g_n`** in a big table, emulate an index skip scan. A basic index does the job:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tbl (g_n);
```

Then:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
   (SELECT g_n FROM tbl ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 1)

   UNION ALL
   SELECT (SELECT g_n FROM tbl WHERE g_n > t.g_n ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 1)
   FROM   t
   WHERE  t.col IS NOT NULL
   )
SELECT count(g_n) FROM t;  -- ignores NULL
```

To also count possible NULL, conditionally add 1:

```sql
...
SELECT count(g_n) + CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT FROM tbl WHERE g_n IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM   t;
```

Again, the `CASE` expression with `EXISTS` is substantially faster for big tables than aggregating like Gordon demonstrated: `max((g_n is null)::int)`.

See:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)